# Cannot see or delete photos from "Synced from iTunes Library"

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

I have an iPhone 6S and Windows PCs. I do not sync photos between the iPhone and PCs. I have about 716MB of space occupied by photos "Synced from iTunes Library" that I cannot see on the iPhone, or have any way to delete them. These photos cannot be found in iCloud either. So this post did not resolve my issue: [Some photos aren't displayed when iPhone connected to PC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267842/some-photos-arent-displayed-when-iphone-connected-to-pc)

I already deleted all of the photos in the Photos app, but I still have the 716MB occupied and have no way to get rid of it. What do I do?

Only 1 photo left in Photos app:
[image]

Still 716MB "Synced from iTunes Library":
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some photos aren't displayed when iPhone connected to PC](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267842/some-photos-arent-displayed-when-iphone-connected-to-pc)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to turn on photo syncing in iTunes? We could try syncing a photo, and then turning off syncing again to see if it deletes the old synced files.