# Missing photos when accessing iPhone via Windows Explorer

Tags: iphone, windows, photos

I always transferred photos from an iPhone to a Windows PC via Windows Explorer, simply by entering the DCIM folder on the phone, navigating to the month folder and copying the files.

Some weeks ago it started that some newly taken photos just do not appear on Windows Explorer. Some do, some do not. Seems random to me.

I'm aware of the fact that iPhones can save photos in iCloud, so they are not accessible via USB, like described here: [Some photos aren't displayed when iPhone connected to PC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267842/some-photos-arent-displayed-when-iphone-connected-to-pc)

In my case, **that's not the cause. iCloud is disabled.**

To localize the problem, I tried the USB import on another Windows PC. And well, all the missing photos were there. So I started transferring my photos to that other PC instead. Worked for a few days, now new pictures are missing there, too.

I tried to make Windows "forget" the iphone by uninstalling/reinstalling the drivers, use another USB port, didn't help. I could find a third PC to access my photos (most probably only working for a few days), but of course that'd be ridiculous.

Any hint what could cause this or what I could try to fix (no workarounds please)? I'm absolutely clueless.

Comment: So, in short the photos are on the phone. BUT Windows is loosing them. Perhaps you are asking on the wrong stack. We don't troubleshoot Windows.

Comment: You might want to try [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) to see if you can extract the images you need. There is a free trial version. _Note: I am only a satisfied customer of Macroplant LLC. No financial or other connections._

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you for your reply, but the error pattern here does not clearly indicate that Windows is messing up things. Since I was deleting phone and drivers from the affected machine, imo there's a chance that iPhone "remembers" the PC and thus causes the problem. I was hoping for a hint on resetting the connection to the specific PC on iPhone respectively make the iPhone "forget" the PC.

Comment: So apply your own hint.